# git flow - how to merge feature branches with --no-ff

Tags: git-flow

I've just started using  **git flow** utility. As I see, when I'm finishing some feature, it merges it to the develop branch, without using --no--ff flag. 
I'd like to use it, so I can see all the development workflow/history in some git GUI tool (e.g. gitk).
Is  there some way to config it, or patch it, so it will merging feature branches with --no-ff flag?

Comment: in the revision I am using at the moment (`0.4.2.20120723`), `--no-ff` is used when finishing a feature that contains more than one commit, while a single commit is merged as fast-forward.

Answer (score 2):

I found this fork, it has support of merging features with --no-ff
https://github.com/petervanderdoes/gitflow